# panda dataframe iterate and adding to set issue

Tags: python, dataframe, set, iteration

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                name
0   [somename1, somename2, n...
1   [name1, someothername, ...
2   [name, name, s...
3   [somename1, name3, s...
4   [name2, name2, s...
5   [somename2, name2, s...
6   [somename1, somename, s...
```

I am trying to iterate through the dataframe and save the data in the dataframe as a sequence in a set. 
Therefore I have done this:

```
events = set([])

for index, row in datarame.iterrows():
    session = row['name']
    print len(session)
    for x in session:
        events.add(x)

print events length total: 
print len(events)
```

What I get as an output here is:

```
    24
    80
    15
    60
    76
    66
    83
    32
    100
    73
    13
    3
    2
    9
    57
    2
    2
    4
    1
    events length total:
    108
```

Which does not make sense. Normally it should add all the contents in the sessions and the length should be the summary of the numbers above, which obviously is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `set` in python is an

> unordered collection of **unique** elements.

It does not allow duplicates.

You should define `event` as a `list` instead.

```
events = []

for index, row in datarame.iterrows():
    session = row['name']
    print len(session)
    for x in session:
        events.append(x)

print events length total: 
print len(events)
```